# How can I set default arguments for "ls" in Linux?

Tags: linux, ls

Im constantly doing "ls -ahl" whenever I want to list what is in the directory.  Is there a way for me to make -ahl the default args passed when I do "ls" or should I just create an alias like "alias lsa=ls -ahl" in bash_profile?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could just alias ls itself. So something like:

```
alias ls='ls -ahl'
```

Comment: you can but it can be annoying if you forget you've done it better to just use a fresh command imo

Answer (score 23):

Set an `alias` in your `~/.bash_profile` file.

```
alias ls="ls -ahl"
```

A couple of common aliases that I use all the time are:

```
alias ll="ls -lh --color"
alias l="ls -1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an alias in your `.bashrc`. You can even call it `ls` and override the program.