# Show hidden files and folders within Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I can't believe I can't find a good solution... I have a hidden folder  named `.venv` that I would like to show in my Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1 terminal output.

I've tried:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

but when I open the terminal in the directory containing `.venv` and type `ls`, the hidden folder is not returned. What gives?

Comment: The `AppleShowAllFiles` controls what you see in Finder, not in Terminal. In Terminal, `ls` will exclude dot files and `ls -a` or `ls -A` will include dot files. You can also add `-a` as a default option, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120435/1271826).

Comment: But, this is off topic for Stack Overflow and will likely be closed as such.

Comment: This works- thanks! My bad about the wrong forum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using the -a flag for ls?

1. To list all files (including hidden files): `$ ls -a`
2. To list all files in a list with more details: `$ ls -al`
3. Alias (shortcut) for 2. `$ ll`

`ls` itself usually ignores entries starting with '.', and the `-a` or `--all` flag ignores that protection.

Use `ls --help` in your terminal to review all available flags.